# CSS - How do I create a grid that takes up the remaining width of screen (without counting sidebar)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a grid in CSS, but I am not sure how to specify the width of the entire grid, such that it takes up only the remaining width of the screen (minus the sidebar) such that there should not be any scrolling horizontally allowed. Below is the screenshot of the issue I am facing.

[image]

As you can see, there is horizontal scrolling enabled, because the grid is too wide.

Here is my code for reference: (I am using ReactJS)

```
.analytics-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  row-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "conversion conversion-daily"
}

.daily-conversion-box {
  grid-area: conversion-daily;
  padding: 20px;
}

.conversion-box {
  grid-area: conversion;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

jsx (where CustomerConversion and CustomerConversionDaily are child components I call to render the charts)

```
<div className='analytics-grid'>
    <div className='conversion-box'>
        <CustomerConversion />
    </div>
    <div className='daily-conversion-box'>
        <CustomerConversionDaily />
    </div>
```

sidebar.js (where Sider is a component from a UI package AntD)

```
<div>
    <Sider trigger={null} collapsible collapsed={collapsed}>
        {menu()}
    </Sider>
    <div id='crm-header-layout'>
        ... *header goes here* ...
        <div id="crm-content">
            {props.children}  //this is where the analytics grid from above end up
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way for me to be able to specify the width of my grid such that it just nice takes up the remaining width of the screen minus the sidebar such that there is no horizontal scrolling to be done? Thanks all for the help, I am new to CSS, so do guide me along if there are any better solutions to accomplish what I want to accomplish! Thank you

Comment: Add `width: 100vw;` to the `.analytics-grid` style.

Answer (score 1):

when you set `display: grid;` it means the children of this node are arranged using grid. It doesn't set the div's height or width for you. You need to set it if you want to contain it.

There are multiple ways to set the width.

1. You can use the grid the same way you've used for container. Like this,

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / 80px 1fr;
}

.content-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.content-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-1">Content 1</div>
  <div class="content-2">Content 2</div>
</div>
```

2. You can contain both the appbar and the content in a flex, and set the `flex-grow` of container to `1`.

```
.app{
  display: flex;
}

.appbar{
flex-grow: 0;
}

.main-container{
flex-grow: 1;
}
```

or,

use CSS `calc` for container like this.

```
.analytics-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  row-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "conversion conversion-daily";
  width: calc(100vw - <appbar width>);
}
```

PS: `grid-template` is short hand to set both row and columns at a time. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template

Comment: thanks for answering! if i were to choose the first method, it means that i have to set the 'analytics-grid' div to width 100%? which method would you recommend? by the way, can I ask, i tried setting the width of the.analytics-grid to a set value, but why is it that the inner charts would exceed the grid width? is that due to some issue with the chart?

Comment: i tried playing around with it, and it seems like the issue is the 1fr 1fr for the columns, when i set it to another value eg vw, the charts within stuck to the correct width, but when im using fr, it exceeds the grid width, any advice on that? thanks in advance! sorry for asking so many questions, im new to CSS

Comment: @jason do not set the `width` property for direct children of the div which has `display:grid`. Their widths are set by the browser after applying the rules of grid. So, width doesn't help you there.

Comment: oh, i am using recharts.js for my charts, and according to their instructions, it seems like i have to set my height and width within the children of the div that has display:grid. I tried setting the height and width of the children to be 100% in hopes that it would follow the grid width, but when i use % in the height and width, the charts become unresponsive to screen size changes. Do you have any advice on how I can integrate chart.js responsiveness with a css grid? Here is the link for the responsiveness on chart.js https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html . Thank you!